# Which one of these Caribbean Islands have the less complicate process to migrate with a EU Passport?

Tags: working-visas

I have an Italian EU Passport, I would like to move to the territory of an EU country, outside Europe (Caribbean Islands). Which one of these islands have the less complicated process and do you have any list of lawyers that can help to complete the process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The French territories of Martinique, Guadeloupe, Saint-Martin and Saint-Barthélemy are **outermost regions** of the European Union. They are outside the Schengen area and the VAT area but otherwise fully apply EU law including freedom of movement for EU citizens.

This means that there is no specific restriction to immigration for EU citizens beyond the usual requirement of having a job or sufficient resources and health insurance (this is also true for mainland France or the rest of the EU). You don't need a visa, a residence permit or a lawyer, really.

The Dutch islands are considered **overseas countries or terrritories** of the EU and they do have restrictions on immigration, even for Dutch citizens.

Lastly, British overseas territories (Anguilla, Bermuda, Montserrat, Cayman Islands, British Virgin Islands and Turks and Caicos Islands) have various rules but they are also considered overseas countries or terrritories of the EU, which means that freedom of movement does not necessarily apply there either.